# Overlapping a center div over two background divs?`

Tags: html, center, alignment

Hey guys probably a n00b question but I want to have two different color divs vertically aligned for the background with their widths being 100% and height being whatever, we'll say 300px for simplicity sake. I then want to center a div which overlaps the other two divs. Any advice? Cheers

Comment: I want two divs the width of the page (100%), and they'll both be on top of each other. I then want to have a div which is centered over top of the other two divs. Lol sorry for the confusion

Comment: How can two divs be on top of each other? Why would a third div overlap the two? The first would be hidden by the second and both by the third.

Comment: Ok I see, let me rephrase. I want two divs for the background - both visible then another div centered overlapping/on the background divs.

Comment: If they're both the width of the page though, only one will show.

Comment: How would I go about doing it? I don't want to use a background image. Hmmmm

Comment: You should provide an image. Your words aren't making sense. Do you need something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gqb7S/

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman have a look here http://freetexthost.com/c3rrt5bjnp

Comment: Thats the BG I just can't overlay a div for the content! :/

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? You didn't provide any specs so its hard to tell what attributes can be hard coded and which cannot. But this should get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/PWwQM/1/

```
#overlay { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: yellow;
    width: 400px; 
    left: 50%;
    top: 75px;
    margin-left: -200px; 
    height: 300px; 
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Hey it works very effectively but the "margin-left: -200px; has me stumped, why is that needed?

Comment: @ImmortalKING You set left: 50% to bring the div into the middle of the page. But you then need to offset by its width a negative amount. The overlay's width is `400`, so must set negative margin of `400/2`

Comment: cheers man! I'm going to university next year and I want to pursue web development but I don't know whether to do software engineering or computer science? Sorry for the questions haha

Comment: @ImmortalKING You should accept mrtsherman's answer. That's how a question "asker" on SO shows his appreciation for correct solution.